# Несколько полей в одно SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

у меня есть таблица ads. В ней есть поля region, city, street.
Я хочу сделать sql запрос и получить их не просто по отдельности, а чтобы их результат был в одном поле.
К примеру сделать что-то такое:

```
SELECT (region + ', ' + city + ',' + street) AS place FROM ads
```

И в итоге чтобы в ответе в поле place было "Краснодарский край, Краснодар, Ул. Ленина".
Подскажите пожалуйста как это реализовать?

Comment: Используйте функцию concat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT concat(region, ', ', city, ', ', street) AS place FROM ads
```